# Ошибка при импортировании класса в android

Tags: java, android

В своем android приложении пытаюсь добавить 2 класса:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
```

Но они не добавляются, `Collectors` и `IntStream` выделяются красным цветом.
В чем может быть проблема? 
Использую Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В  предыдущих версия Android возможность использовать Java 8 отсутствует. Но в Android 7 такая возможность появилась. Вот ссылка на [официальную документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=ru)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию:)